# Export function for Excel in PHP

Tags: php, excel, spreadsheet, xlsx, phpspreadsheet

I have a problem with the export function for Excel in my PHP file, the file is generated and downloaded but when i try to open it i got the following error message in excel :

Excel cannot open the file 'employee_attendance_2023-07-22.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

This is the code i am using :

```
function exportToExcel($data)
{
    require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

    $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();

    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

    // Set table headers
    $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Employee ID');
    $sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'Check-in');
    $sheet->setCellValue('C1', 'Check-out');
    $sheet->setCellValue('D1', 'Working Time');

    $row = 2;
    foreach ($data as $rowdata) {
        $sheet->setCellValue('A' . $row, $rowdata['employee_id']);
        $sheet->setCellValue('B' . $row, $rowdata['check_in_time']);
        $sheet->setCellValue('C' . $row, $rowdata['check_out_time']);

        $totalTime = strtotime($rowdata['check_out_time']) - strtotime($rowdata['check_in_time']);
        $hours = floor($totalTime / 3600);
        $minutes = floor(($totalTime % 3600) / 60);
        $sheet->setCellValue('D' . $row, $hours . ' hours ' . $minutes . ' minutes');

        $row++;
    }

    $filename = 'employee_attendance_' . date('Y-m-d') . '.xlsx';

    $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);

    $tempFile = tempnam('/tmp', 'excel_export');
    $writer->save($tempFile);

    header('Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $filename . '"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    readfile($tempFile);
    unlink($tempFile);
    exit;
}
```

I tried to change the header content type but still the same issue.

Comment: Save the downloaded file somewhere, rename it to a .txt extension and open it with a text editor. Chances are pretty good that there's some error message or the like embedded in there somewhere that's breaking it.